# Is it required for you to put the preinstalled libraries of python in requirements.txt(Such as NumPy, math, etc.)?

Tags: python, travis-ci

I want to know for my project if I need to include the core python libraries into the requirements file if I am using them in my project. This is for Travis CI build system, and I am trying to build the project, and it uses Numpy, and math.

Comment: Numpy is not a core library.

Comment: You don't have to put standard library modules in `requirements.txt`, but `numpy` isn't one of them: https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html

Comment: So do I need to put it in the requirements.txt file? I am sorry, I am pretty new to this system

Comment: In your example, `numpy` should be in requirements, `math` should not.

Comment: You can use something like [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) to autogenerate at least a first version of your requirements.txt.

Comment: If you have a requirement for a certain version of `math` it can be done by specifyhing the `python_version` its in. That's likely something you want anyway because of ongoing addition of language features.

Comment: Can’t you automatically generate the requirements.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any modules that are part of Python’s standard library such as `math`, `os`, `sys`, etc do not need to be listed in your `requirements.txt` file.

Any third party libraries that you include within your project using `pip install ______` will need to be added.

You can find a list of standard modules included within core Python at [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html).

You can also enter the following command within a Python interpreter session to see them listed in your terminal.

`>>> help('modules')`